# Infragistics UltraDockManager - Maximized DockAreas Cover Entire Form

Tags: .net, winforms, infragistics

I am curious as to if it is possible to force an entire DockArea to fill the entire form that the DockManager is hosted.

I know there is a property that will fill the remaining space with the last DockArea created, however that is not satisfactory.  I really need it to overlay the rest of the DockAreas when maximized and when minimized to go back to the location in which it was docked originally.

I hope I made that clear enough.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [WinTilePanel](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/current/CLR2.0/?page=WinTilePanel_About_WinTilePanel.html) may be a better control to use to have a single maximized pane at a time.  You could hide the other tiles by setting the visible property to false if you need the tile to take the entire area of the control.  Note that this doesn't allow floating panes/tiles.